# Laravel backend to Vue not displaying correctly sorted data

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Simple situation: Fetching all rows from DB with Laravel controller and display them with Vue.

Laravel produces correctly sorted (by name) results from model however when fetched via Vue and looped over to display in an HTML table they are shown as the order they're stored in the DB.

Controller:

```
public function readCountryAll()
{
    $data = World::Countries()->sortBy('name');
    //return response()->json($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Vue:

```
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr v-for="country in countryList" :key="country.code">
            <td>{{ country.code }}</td>
            <td>{{ country.full_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ country.currency_code }}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
 <script>

  export default {

    mounted: function() { 
           this.read();
    },

    data() {
      return {
        countryList: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {

      read() {
        window.axios.get('/readCountry')
            .then(response => this.countryList = response.data)
      },
    },
    components: {

    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you check what your response is by accessing the url manually? so via the browser and check what order it comes in

Comment: Are you sure that in vue url should be readCountry and not readCountryAll?

Comment: why did you comment the //return response()->json($data)// part ?

Comment: if you dd($data) are you looking them in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

When data is sent via JSON order will be random. What you need to do is create a computed property in vuejs which can be called "sortedCountryList" and do your sorting there. Then you can use this computed property wherever you need to output sorted list.

```
 <script>

  export default {

    mounted: function() { 
           this.read();
    },

    data() {
      return {
        countryList: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {

      read() {
        window.axios.get('/readCountry')
            .then(response => this.countryList = response.data)
      },
    },
    computed: {
            sortedCountryList: function() {
               return this.countryList.sort(function (a, b) {
                   return b.name - a.name;
               });

            },
    },
    components: {

    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried computed properties and it still wont sort. Is there a different with Laravel returning a collection vs an array?

Comment: Also when I sort the data via the Laravel controller it seems to be ordering the Vue object by both ID and then Name. I feel like Vue is defaulting to sort it by the table ID.

Answer (score 0):

This Solved my issue.

```
  computed: {
    sortedArray: function() {
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.name < b.name)
          return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }

      return this.countryList.sort(compare);
    }
  }
```